# cannot find a way to install php's pecl bbcode exentsion

Tags: php

Is there an easy way to install php's pecl bbcode extension on ubuntu? When using it on LAMP?

Comment: For what propose? If it's for forums/wiki the `php-text-wiki` package will be useful.

Comment: To use the bbcode functions in php.

Comment: These http://search.cpan.org/~blom/HTML-BBCode-2.07/lib/HTML/BBCode.pm ?

Answer (score 0):

Type the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear
pecl install bbcode
```

They are same, I hope that helps.

Comment: @Braiam updated .

Comment: Doesn't work see here: http://pastebin.com/LSKZ2cNz